# Gathering some data for a network graph in D3. How should I format it?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

I am gathering data to create a network graph using the D3 JavaScript library.

What is the best format to work with? My thinking is a database with the schema

```
Source Node, Relation, Destination Node
```

Should anything else be taken into account here?

All I want is to show a simple relationship between people. Let's say I want to graph everyone on facebook whos is friends in one geographic area (just an example).

So let's assume I have a dataset of people from London.

So, if I gather the source persons ID, their relationship with another person ("friends" or "subscribed to"), and the ID of the other person, then I can display this graphically using D3, yes?

Is this the ideal way to gather my data?

I've tried looking at the D3 manual, but it is not 100% clear to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the sample data at the bottom of this example: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045. When using d3's force layout, you'll need two arrays: one listing the nodes, and one listing the links. The "group" and "value" variables are specific to this example (i.e. not required), although in your case the relationship you mention could be substituted for "value". So you're database table would match well with the "links" array and you could then construct the nodes array from that.